# Selection sort in C

Tags: c, sorting

```
void selectionSortC()
{
    //Not wasting time inputting arrary
    int arr[6] = { 2,4,-22,4,2,1 };

    size_t minIdx = 0;
    int len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] > arr[j])
            {
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should never write "non-prototype style" functions in C, it's an obsolete feature. That is, never write `void selectionSortC()`, always write `void selectionSortC(void)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Missing includes

We need to include `<stdio.h>` (for `printf`); this also defines `size_t` for us (but see next item).

## Don't mix I/O with algorithms

The code is hard to re-use, because we can't give a different array to sort, or do anything with the result apart from printing.  Prefer an interface like this:

```
#include <stddef.h>  /* for size_t */

void selection_sort(int *array, size_t len);
```

We can use it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = { 2, 4, -22, 4, 2, 1 };
    const size_t len = sizeof arr / sizeof *arr;

    selection_sort(arr, len);

    for (size_t i = 0;  i < len;  ++i) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    puts("");
}
```

## Unused variable

What's the point of `minIdx`? We never use it after it's initialised.

## Use appropriate types

We should be using `size_t` for lengths and indices, rather than `int`.

---

## Modified code

Here's what I arrived at after making the improvements above:

```
#include <stddef.h>

void selection_sort(int *arr, size_t len)
{
    for (size_t i = 0;  i < len;  i++) {
        for (size_t j = i + 1;  j < len;  j++) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[j]) {
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = { 2, 4, -22, 4, 2, 1 };
    const size_t len = sizeof arr / sizeof *arr;

    selection_sort(arr, len);

    for (size_t i = 0;  i < len;  ++i) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    puts("");
}
```